# Changes in league of legends champions

Tags: league-of-legends

I understand that from time to time there are changes with champions attributes. Sometimes weaken and sometimes reinforce champions.
Where can i see those changes?

Comment: Have a look here: [LoL Patch Notes](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few platforms are available.

They are regularly updated on the [main page](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/) under [Patch Notes](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch).

Also there are a few other league-related sites which regularly update news and patch notes ([Surrender@20](https://www.facebook.com/SurrenderAt20/), [nerfplz.lol](http://www.nerfplz.com/), etc).